# How to add a node js emit event in server side to emit new records inserted in database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, socket.io

I'm developing a node js socket backend that needs to emit new records to client.

What i mean is , imagine i have a mysql database , and node js is running , i want to emit any new record that is inserted in the database in realtime  , exactly that particular last inserted record .

Now i'm using node js timer , and this timer  is checking database and emiting all records to client every 1 second , i dont want this .

I searched alot but not found anything like this .
thanks for any suggestion .

Answer (score 0):

One possible way that has been explored before is to listen to [Mysql's Binary log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log.html), also abbreviated **binlog**.

Here are two packages related to it:

- A first package, called **Zongji**, aimed to be a Mysql binlog listener: [Npm - zongji](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zongji).
- A second package, called **mysql-events**, using the first package to listen to events in a more convenient way: [Npm - mysql-events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-events)

The second package has a well-detailed documentation that should allow you to get started on listening to Mysql updates in no time.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is to emit the event just after saving the record to db e.g

// Supose using mongodb and node

```
  let newStudent = new Student(studentToBeRegistered);
  newStudent.save().then((data: any) => {
     // on success
     // emit socket
     socket.emit('newRecord', data)
    }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
    });
```